# llvm-g++ creates multithreaded application

Tags: macos, gcc, llvm

I have recently got a new MacBook Air and I'm continuing my development in OS X using Qt Creator as the IDE. I don't know much about `llvm` compiler, but Qt Creator's debugger shows 4 threads when I run the application. I have installed Xcode and Qt Creator is using `llvm-g++` for the compiler.

In Linux, I can create multithreaded application with gcc if I pass `-fopenmp` to the compiler and linker and use appropriate directives but `llvm` seems to do this on its own. How can I prevent it?

Comment: What kind of application are you developing? If its a GUI or networked application (suggested by the fact that you're using Qt Creator) - then the additional threads are probably related to rendering the GUI or maintaining the I/O. In that case you can't/shouldn't try to get rid of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LLVM does not introduce threads into your application. QT is creating the threads for its own purposes, probably using the pthreads API.

Comment: but I'm not linking against pthreads and I use the same code on Linux with Qt Creator and this does not happen there. How could this be?

Comment: qt is probably linked against pthreads. Doesn't matter whether you linked it in or not; qt pulls it in. WRT Linux, there's nothing that says that qt has to work identically on Mac OS; indeed, there's many reasons that it'd work differently.